# What is the stop() function do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What the stop() function do.. ? and for what is it  ?
Who can explain why it uses here... I know what is doing the stop() fuction but here i dont understand whay is there... Thx Elod

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
        var topPadding = 15;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Check this link for explanation: http://api.jquery.com/stop/. It is used to stop currently running animation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation for `.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

> Description: Stop the currently-running animation on the matched
>   elements.
>
> When .stop() is called on an element, the currently-running animation
>   (if any) is immediately stopped. If, for instance, an element is being
>   hidden with .slideUp() when .stop() is called, the element will now
>   still be displayed, but will be a fraction of its previous height.
>   Callback functions are not called.

In other words, in your example, all animations on elements with the id `#sidebar` are stopped, and immediately afterwards, a new animation is started.

Further more, why is it needed in the first place? To cause the new animation to happen instantaneously. Again, from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

> If more than one animation method is called on the same element, the
>   later animations are placed in the effects queue for the element.
>   These animations will not begin until the first one completes.When .stop() is called, the next animation in the queue begins immediately.

Comment: Ok i know what stop is doing but here i dont understand whay is there.. if i dont put the stop the animation looks strange.. like skipping the frames

Comment: @ElodAndras, I added a bit more. I'm not sure what else there is to say.